# Переименование одинаковых файлов

Tags: wordpress, cms

Стандартно если загружать в wordpress'e файлы с одинаковым именем, то в конце ставиться цифра без пробела (т.е file, file1, file2), а как сделать чтобы он одинаковые файлы переименовывал таким образом (file, file-1, file-2).
Т.е. нужно чтобы он ставил дефис

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именование файлов идет в функции `wp_unique_filename`. Находится она в `functions.php`. Если надо - перепишите ее в своем `functions.php`, изменив шаблон именования по своему вкусу.

Comment: @mzd, там можно не менять функцию, а вызывать свою через указание имени в `$overrides['upload_error_handler']` судя по коду. Пример тут http://www.faqoverflow.com/wordpress/28439.html